# Delete max element in array

Tags: java, arrays

Wrote some code to try to find the maximum element in an un-ordered array and then delete it from the array. My first loop has the logic to find the maximum element while the second loop should take in the variable from the first loop, look ahead one space and then insert into the max element.

My below code seems to work for my second idea .. but does not find the right max array element.

My array has the following values {6, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 4}. It is finding the max array element to be 7 .. it should be 9.

```
   public void deleteMax() {
  // set value for comparison starting from the beginning of the array 
  int arrayMax = arr[0]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
     if (arr[i] > arrayMax) {
        arrayMax = arr[i];

        for (int k = i; k < nElems; k++) {
           arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
           nElems--;

           break;
         }
      }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just `sort()` the array and then grab the first element? Something like `var max = ary.sort(function (a, b) { return a > b; }).pop();`

Comment: Array has to be unsorted ..

Comment: Why does it have to be unsorted when you do the arithmetic?

Comment: @Chewy if it can't be sorted can it just be reduced? `arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
});`

Comment: @Joe filter : its ! =, ! == cannot be used :)

Answer (score 1):

why not use jQuery $.grep & Math.max like:

```
var arr = [6, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 4];
var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, arr);

var newArr = $.grep( arr, function( n ) {
  return n != maxNum;
});
console.log(newArr);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pb0LL0L/)

EDIT:
Well didn't realize you're using **Java** as the question showed in JavaScript section...

in Java, You can find max number in array like

```
int maxNum = arr.get(0); // get the first number in array
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ( arr.get(i) > maxNum) {
      maxNum = array.get(i);
    }
}
arr.remove(maxNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,, you don't need any second loop.

Only one loop and two variables called, f.ex. MaxElementPosition and MaxElementValue, which are updated every time inside the loop if the number on this position is greater than the last MaxElementValue, update both value and position.

While the loop you do need the value for comparing. In the end you only need the position.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is irrelevant, you only have a 1D array, so it makes no sense to do any inner iteration.

If you insist on performing no `sorting` on the array, then you could do something like this:

```
public void deleteMax() {
   // set value for comparison starting from the beginning of the array 
   int arrayMax = arr[0]; 
   int maxIndex = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
       if (arr[i] > arrayMax) {
          arrayMax = arr[i];
          maxIndex = i;
       }
   }

   arr.remove(maxIndex);
}
```

Once the `for` loop finishes, we remove the item at maxIndex

Comment: Ok .. Couldn't I just get the next element starting at the max and then swap max with arr[i + 1]. How would I do that though ?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?  This will always have the max value and its corresponding index which you can remove at - any additional complexity is un-necessary

Answer (score 0):

@Alex is on the right track, but there is no remove function that can be called on an array in java.  All that you need is the variable maxIndex that he gets, which of course will be the first occurence of this maximum, so if you need to remove every occurence of the maximum, that would be a different issue.  So once you use @Alex code:

```
int arrayMax = arr[0]; 
int maxIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
   if (arr[i] > arrayMax) {
      arrayMax = arr[i];
      maxIndex = i;
   }
}
```

This would be much easier if instead of an array, you were to use an ArrayList, in which case the code would look like:

```
int arrayMax = arr.get(0); 
int maxIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
   if (arr[i] > arrayMax) {
      arrayMax = arr[i];
      maxIndex = i;
   }
}
arr.remove(maxIndex);
```

Otherwise you would have to create a temp array to remove the value:

```
int[] temp = new int[arr.length-1];
    for(int i = 0, index = 0; index < nElems; i++, index++)
    {
        if(index == maxIndex) index++;
        temp[i] = arr[index];
    }
    arr = temp;
```